# How to instantiate Python class with __enter__ method in another Python class constructor

Tags: python

I have a Python class where the constructor creates a MySQL database connection as follows:

```
class MySQL:
def __init__(self):
    self.client = self.get_client()

def get_client():
    client = pymysql.connect(**mysql_credentials)
    return client
```

The problem with this implementation is that the connection never ends. So I want to modify the class to create the database connection in the `__enter__` method and close the connection on `__exit__` method as follows:

```
class MySQL:
def __enter__(self):
    self.client = self.get_client()
    
def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
    self.client.close()

def get_client():
    client = pymysql.connect(**mysql_credentials)
    return client

def execute_query(self, sql_query: str):
    with self.client.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(sql_query)
```

Now the question. How can instantiate MySQL class with `__enter__` and `__exit__` inside the constructor of another class?

Can't be do like this because it calls MySQL `__init__` method and it will not open the connection:

```
class AnotherClass:
def __init__(self):
    self.mysql_cli = MySQL()

def run_etl(self):
    self.mysql_cli.execute_query('''SELECT VERSION();''')
```

Any suggestions?

Many thanks!

Comment: I think you may have simplified your code so much for example purposes that it's not very clear what you need for your real problem. Does `AnotherClass` need to be using its instance of `MySQL` for its entire lifetime, or just for the duration of the `__init__` method (or something in between)? Can `AnotherClass` become a context manager too?

Comment: `MySQL` should be deallocated when it goes out of all scopes it’s used in, and with it the pymysql instance and its connection should be deallocated as well. No need for anything special.

Comment: @deceze: Relying upon garbage collection for management of non-memory cleanup is very sketchy. That's why the manager protocol exists! But it's not clear how `AnotherClass` uses `MySQL`, so it's impossible to answer except in very broad generalities.

Comment: @Blckknght AnotherClass need to be using its instance of MySQL for its entire lifetime. Sorry for the unclarity.

Comment: @Blckknght check the edit please. maybe can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three different ways for a class to properly use a context manager inside its own code.

One option is for the new class to be a context manager itself, so its users can do the managing of the connection lifetimes through it. This is pretty straight forward, just call the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods of your contained context manager from your own versions of those methods. That might look like this:

```
class AnotherClass:
    def __init__(self):
       self.db = MySQL()

    def __enter__(self):
       self.db.__enter__()
       return self

    def __exit__(self, *exc_args):
        return self.db.__exit__(*exc_args)

    def do_stuff(self):
        # do stuff with the database
```

The burden of managing the connection is delegated to the user of the class, who can use `with` statements on their `AnotherClass` instance:

```
with AnotherClass() as another:
    another.do_stuff()
```

This approach can get tedious though if you have lots of layers of aggregation, and need all the intermediate containers to become context managers just because they contain one at some much lower level.

Another approach is to make separate database connections for each operation that needs to use the database for something. This lets you use `with` statements for the connection management, but may require that you do a lot more connecting and reconnecting than you'd like:

```
class AnotherClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = MySQL()

    def do_stuff(self):
        with self.db:
            # do the actual stuff here, using the database
```

With this design, the user of `AnotherClass` doesn't need to use the context manager protocol because the database connections are only alive during the runtime of the methods you call.

```
another = AnotherClass()
another.do_stuff() # creates and destroys the db connection internally
```

The third option is to say that `AnotherClass` should not be involved with the connection management of the `MySQL` class it uses. That's the responsibility of some other part of the code, and we don't even need to know about it here. For this approach, you probably want the `MySQL` instance to be created elsewhere (wherever it is being managed) and have it be passed in as an argument to the `AnotherClass` constructor:

```
class AnotherClass:
    def __init__(self, db):
        self.db = db

    def do_stuff(self):
        # do stuff with the database
```

The caller would do something like this:

```
 db = MySQL()
 with db:
     another = AnotherClass(db)
     another.do_stuff()
```

This has the advantage that the `db` object passed in to `AnotherClass` can be whatever type you want, as long as it has the APIs that `AnotherClass` expects. If you need to change your database from MySQL to Postgres, you don't need to change `AnotherClass`, only the higher level code.

Comment: Many many thanks for the detailed explanation @Blackknt! Thanks